# Importing pages using my own code based on jQuery inspired from Angular

Tags: jquery, angular, import

I am attempting to write my own page import functionality in a new web framework I am working on. When I import pages the code works perfectly well, however as soon as i nest page imports (meaning import a page that imports a page) the JavaScript file goes into a loop apparently because my computer starts accelerating CPU usage and the fan gets really loud and after a while brackets text editor closes due to an error.

Can anyone tell me why the following code is causing a loop and how I can fix the code?

```
JS file 

var beam = $('[re=beam]');
beam.each(function() {
    $(this).load($(this).attr('re-beam'));
});      

HTML File

<div re-beam="p1.html"><div>
<div re-beam="p2.html"><div>
<div re-beam="p3.html"><div>
```

So p1 and p2.html will load perfectly well but inside p3.html i have another import exactly like above (so p3.html has inside it another div which imports p4.html and p4 doesn't import anything) and that's when there is this "infinite loop".

Comment: What is p3.html importing? Is it loading another page that again loads p3.html?

Comment: no of course not. its loading another page p4.html which doesn't import anything

Comment: Did you mean `$('[re-beam]')` versus `$('[re=beam]')`?

Comment: yeah sorry the first one re=beam is a typo, should be re-beam (what i meant). thanks for that

Comment: No one has an answer?